# Allow non-root user setfacl on root-owned file

Tags: linux, security, permissions, root

I have an application `manager` that needs to call `setfacl` to (dis-)allow execution of a certain file by certain users.

This application runs as a non-root user `admin` (and for a plethora of reasons, I'd like to keep it that way). Therefore the `setfacl` calls from within `manager` fail with `setfacl: <filename>: Operation not permitted`.

My understanding is, that I could give the `admin` user the `CAP_FOWNER` capability to allow it using `setfacl` on files owned by `root`.
I tried doing so, by adding `cap_fowner           admin` to `/etc/security/capability.conf`.
After re-logging in `admin`, the cap is set:

```bash
$ capsh --print
Current: = cap_fowner+i
...
```

`setfacl` still fails though:

```bash
$ setfacl -b <filename>
setfacl: <filename>: Operation not permitted
```

The file currently has the following acl:

```bash
$ getfacl <filename>
# file: <filename>
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:cluster-user2:r--
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
```

I also tried `sudo setcap cap_fowner=ie manager` (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69413616/3452807)) but that does not seem to enable `manager` to use `setfacl` internally either.

I'm happy about any clues how to enable using `setfacl` as a non-root user on root-owned files.

Eventually, I want to run the `manager` as a systemd service using the user `admin`. Is there a systemd way to add the required capability?

Comment: Is this a local file or is it served via NFS/SMB/etc?

Comment: It's in `/usr/bin`, installed by a deb package. Which is why I'm hesitant to just change the file's owner.

Comment: Try `sudo setcap CAP_FOWNER=+eip /path/to/binary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were looking for is the "ambient" capability set – a much later addition to Linux, which pam_cap does not yet support.

Current version of pam_cap only manages "inheritable" capabilities, which per original [design](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) only become effective if the *file being executed* (i.e. /usr/bin/setfacl) also has that capability marked as "inheritable" using `setcap cap_fowner=ei <path>`.

(**Not** `cap_fowner=eip`, as marking the capability as "permitted" would grant CAP_FOWNER rights to the program when executed by *any* user, even if the user hasn't been granted it via PAM.)

For packaged files, use `dpkg-statoverride` to change their owner permanently. Alternatively, grant the user *sudo* rights to run the single command `setfacl -m * <filename>` as root.

Comment: Thanks! All the options seem to solve the issue permanently and don't seem overly invasive. Will evaluate which to deploy in prod.

Comment: Not entirely – setting capabilities on /bin/setfacl is very much like changing the owner of /bin/setfacl, and would also be lost after a package upgrade.